# Считывание файла в массив Java

Tags: java

Есть файл, содержавший число: test.txt

```
1234523432
```

Как считать число в массив, посимвольно, и определить, есть ли в данном числе четные цифры и сколько их?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Можно использовать Stream Api, файл res.txt должен находиться в ресурсах:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        List<Integer> list = Files.lines(Paths.get(Main.class.getResource("res.txt").toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                .map(s -> s.split(""))
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .map(Integer::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
        int chet = (int) list.stream().filter(s -> s % 2 == 0).count();
        System.out.println(chet!=0?"Число четных: " + chet:"Нет четных");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать следующим образом:

```js
import java.io.*;

public class script {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  FileInputStream io = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
  int countOfEven = 0;
  BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(io));
  String line;
  while( (line = r.readLine()) != null ){
   for(char ch : line.toCharArray()){
    if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ch)) % 2 == 0){
     countOfEven++;
    }
   }
  }
  if(countOfEven != 0){
   System.out.println("Число имеет четные цифры");
   System.out.println("Количество - " + countOfEven);
  }else{
   System.out.println("Число не имеет четных цифр");
  }
 
 }
}
```